# javascript object vs array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on a javascript plugin at work which will take an array of elements and display it in a customized way (sorting, order of columns, criterias) in a table.
The customization options will be created dynamically (date property will produce 'before' criteria etc).

The plugin will be used in many different projects so the elements can vary a lot and as the display is customized the properties needed for each table creation varies as well.

**Should I ask for the elements as objects or as arrays?**

Basically (not real code - I will not use foreach ;) what is done is this:

```
foreach element in allelements
row=new tablerow
foreach columnid in chosencolumns
    row.add(element[columnid])
table.add(row)
```

If each element is an array the columnid is the index but if each element it will be the property name.

Is element[3] faster than element['prop3']?

I have made a [Beta version here](http://datareporting.99k.org/) which have the elements stored as arrays but I am not sure if that is the best/fastest way

EDIT: Due to the nature of the project ordering of the properties of an element is not important.
**ALSO: which way will consume more memory? Some systems will consist of many elements with many properties so memory might be an issue :-/**

SECOND EDIT: 
If I use objects I would also need to make an array of property names for the object.
So if the user chose to have the view consist of the 13th, 2nd and 4th property as column 1, 2 and 3 I would need to do the following for each element

```
row.add(element[propertynames[13]])
row.add(element[propertynames[2]])
row.add(element[propertynames[4]])
```

Whereas if I chose the array solution I would 'save' the propertynames lookup:

```
row.add(element[13])
row.add(element[2])
row.add(element[4])
```

Comment: "Is element[3] faster than element['prop3']?" --- it doesn't matter. Don't waste your time, fix some bugs and implement some **really useful** things instead.

Comment: Just be aware that object keys are *not* ordered.

Comment: Also, whenever you're using `for ... in`, be sure to also check for `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @ zerkms It matters a great deal. Imagine a 'medium sized system' with 5000 elements each containing 20 properties/fields and a user requesting a sorted view with 2 criterias. That will require a lot of look ups!

Comment: @zerkms by the way: which bugs? and which really useful things? :)

Comment: @Rune Jeppesen: the real tasks. Every project has bugs, tasks and improvements queue.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few criterias which might be an *Argument* to prefer one data-structure over the other, but that would lead to a subjective discussion.

However, the most significant question you should ask yourself is,
*do you need/want the data to appear in order and/or sorted?*

If the answer is yes, you should go with an *Array*. Object *keys* are by spec unordered. You can of course loop and sort the keys, but again, it depends on the kind of data and how you want to read it.

---

If you go with a *Javascript Array* (which still is an object), you definitely don't want to loop over its contents via `for..in`. That is the slowest possible technique for non-functional loops. Go with `while`, `for` or `do-while` instead.

It sounds like you're talking about a real large data amount. In general you want to avoid that if possible. Try to read and transfer the data in smaller chunks or maybe streaming the data might be better options. Also, if there is a lot to transfer, *data structure* will become a factor. Like *object notation* has in general *more structure information* than simple *Arrays*.

Comment: Why is that storing data client side should be avoided? If the data is transfered in smaller chunks (starting with the newest) and we have no phone/tablet users. I think it will be much faster than 'talking' with the server each time the users requests a new report/view.

Comment: @RuneJeppesen: It depends on what you mean with 'client side'. If that means to load all that data into a browsers DOM, that will ultimately become horrific slow. If you *just* want to load and cache the data on memory, it might work out well. Anyway, you might not want to *waste* users memory with data he doesn't even can access yet.

Comment: I am not sure if I am loading the data into the browsers DOM - I am storing the data in javascript object? Also to your original post regarding structure information: Does that mean that [['James Bond',8,40],['Superman',9999,36]] use less memory than [{Name,'James Bond',strength:8,coolness:40},{{Name,'Superman',strength:9999,coolness:36}?